# Angularjs: How to filter the list with multiple value(including hidden value)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to add filter in my page. It is working fine when i tried to filter the list with one item, But i want to include multiple value as well as hidden value to query with

My controller-

```
$scope.updateSearch = function () {
$scope.filtered = $filter($scope.tracks, {name: $scope.search.id});
};
  $scope.resetFilters = function () {
  $scope.search = {};
};
```

My jsp-

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
<input type="text" ng-model="search.id"   ng-change="updateSearch()"class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid"></div>
```

In the above example I tried to filter using id value, but wanted to include other value like orderId, itemId, lastName . 
Can you please tell me how to do that? any help or suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

> {name:"M", phone:"1"} predicate will return an array of items which
>   have property name containing "M" and property phone containing "1". A
>   special property name $ can be used (as in {$:"text"}) to accept a
>   match against any property of the object or its nested object
>   properties.

Filter documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Lets say `$scope.search.id = 1` then

`$scope.filtered = $filter($scope.tracks, {$: $scope.search.id});` will filter all results where `lastName` or `orderId` or `itemId` or `name` or any property (including hidden) that matches with `1`

Lets say `$scope.search.name = 'John' and $scope.search.orderId = 123`, then

`$scope.filtered = $filter($scope.tracks, {name: $scope.search.id, orderId: $scope.search.orderId});` filters those orders under `name John` and `orderId 123`.

I am afraid, I haven't understood which one you want. So, I gave both multiple filter search and multiple property search solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.. Got lot of clarification

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by applying multiple conditions.

```
$scope.filtered = $filter($scope.tracks, 
    {id: $scope.search.id,orderId: $scope.search.orderId,itemId:$scope.search.itemId,lastName:$scope.search.lastName});
```